# Creating Runnable Jar

Tags: maven, jar, pom.xml

I have two mavenized projects my_project1 and my_project2 in the same folder. Both of them have their own POM file. One project is dependent upon other.

Now I would like to create a runnable jar and thus I use maven shade plugin. However I get the following error:

Could not find artifact my_project1 in maven2-repository...

How can I specify the path to project my_project1 so that I overcome this error. Btw. is this plugin going to upload my project to the maven repository?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Could not find artifact my_project1 in maven2-repository...` means, that maven can't find the project in the build reactor nor in your local repository. You can solve this by install the missing project to your local repository with `mvn install my_project1` (need to do this after codechange again), or add the project to the build reactor by creating a parent project using [aggregation](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html).

Your artifacts won't be uploaded to any remote repository.